# How to copy specific data after check box is selected in VBA Excel 2010?

Tags: vba, excel

**DATA:** I have 3 columns and 1 check box. I can add data in the first column only.

**What i want to do** is that when i select the check box, the data copies to the 2nd & third column, and when it is unchecked the data is removed from 2nd & 3rd.

**What I'm doing** is that I'm recording a macro that:

1. Selected the range of the source column
2. Then i copied it.
3. Selected the range's of both the columns and pasted the values.
4. Stop recording the macro
5. Now right click on the check box and assigned this macro to the check box.

The macro's code is

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("B4:B8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D4:D8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("F4:F8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

**Problems I'm facing** is that the data copies to the 2nd and 3rd column but the selection bar remains blinking on the 1st column, and secondly is i cant un-assign the data when the check box is un-checked. like this:

[image: Populated Columns]

I've tried to record another macro of the reverse case but I can't assign 2 macros to the same check box & how to un-assign the data when the check box is un-checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather this is an ActiveX Control Check Box that you inserted using Developer ► Controls ► Insert ► ActiveX Controls ► Check Box.

[image: ActiveX Check Box]

With Design Mode turned on, right-click the checkbox control and choose **View Code** from the content menu.

[image: ActiveX Check Box Meuu]

This should open you up to the VBE in an empty `CheckBox1_Click` private sub. The name (CheckBox1) may differ depending on what your actual control is named. Paste the following modification into that blank sub.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value Then
        Range("D4:D8") = Range("B4:B8").Value
        Range("F4:F8") = Range("B4:B8").Value
    Else
        Range("D4:D8,F4:F8").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet. Turn Design Mode off (Developer ► Controls ► Design Mode) so the control becomes operational.

Clicking the checkbox on and off will alternately populate D4:D8 and F4:F8 or clear them.

Comment: @AbdulWahab - No worries. Glad that got you sorted out. Thank you for taking the time to post the code into the question instead of leaving it in an image.